# How to use two or more annotations for a class at the same time

Tags: java, jackson, annotations

I have a class called animal and I need to use both `JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT` annotation and `JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT` on it. I have used it in the following way.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
public class Animal{}
```

However, it gives out an error saying

> Duplicate annotation. The declaration of
> 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude' does not have a valid
> java.lang.annotation.Repeatable annotation

How can I overcome this error and use both annotations at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The `@JsonInclude` annotation can take multiple values (at least, if you're not using a very old version of Jackson). Instead of trying to use two annotations, use one with multiple values:

```
@JsonInclude(values = { JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT, JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT })
```

Comment: Now it says "Illegal initializer for 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include'"

Comment: @AkilaRanasinghe Are you using a version of Jackson that supports this, or are you using an old version that does not?

Comment: I am using 2.13.3 version